# KB2465367 and 3rd party libraries

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using third party libraries that I obtained well before KB2465367 came out.  My development computer has been updated with KB2465367 so all the binaries I generate seem to now be dependant on 8.0.50727.5592 of the CRT (the 2465367 version of the CRT).

Now, when I want to deploy this application I'm using the 8.0 CRT merge module (also updated by 2465367).  This installs 8.0.50727.5592 versions of MSVC libraries (like msvcrt80.dll).

But, when I run my application on a machine that's never had the VC runtime installed, it complains about "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."  I've traced this back to a system entry in the event log: "Generate Activation Context failed for C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyApp.exe. Reference error message: The operation completed successfully." under the source "SideBySide".

Of course, this update has basically meant I'm dead in the water.

How do I proceed from here?  Do my clients need to install 8.0.50608.0 version of the CRT *after* installing my application because the 3rd party libraries need 8.0.50608.0 and the MSM I used didn't include it?

---

In my circumstance I'm using [How To: Install the Visual C++ Redistributable with your installer](http://lynk.at/lj4Fb5) which only describes using a single MSM.  It's recommended that a policy MSM also be used to redirect any DLLs dependant on older versions of the runtime. 
 See also http://lynk.at/jlqsKx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same thing happened when MS rolled out KB971090.
A simple solution is to remove the KB2465367.

You can reference more information about KB971090 and KB2465367 at [here.](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/kb2465367-a-repeat-of-the-kb971090-roll-out-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an [uninitialized data bug in the patch](http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2011/04/14/bug-black-patchday-for-all-os-from-xp-and-later-3-mfc-8-0-vc-2005-or-mfc-9-0-vc-2008-linked-dynamically-to-the-mfc-may-not-find-the-mfc-language-dlls-after-installation-of-the-security-packs-d/) that can cause DLL load failure.

Comment: This is a SideBySide issue in that my third party DLL is dependant on a version of msvc that isn't available. Nothing is being run yet; so, it can't possibly reach any code with a potential bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation program have to use two merge modules:

1. The runtime libraries, and
2. The policy file which redirects all older versions of the runtime to the new version.

The redistributable package `vcredist_xxx.exe` installs both the latest version of the libraries and the policy files.

---

You cannot assume the VC libraries are available on users machines, therefore you always have to install them. Otherwise your application won't run.